# Is collection framework implementation generic, before Java 1.5?

Tags: java, generics, collections

In java generic feature was implemented in 1.5 version, before 1.5 how could be the implementation of collection framework classes?

Ex :

ArrayList can hold any type even before java 1.5 version. How could be this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collections just held references to `Object`s. Wherever you retrieved something from a collection you had to down cast it to the desired type.

Here seems to be some old lecture notes with pre 1.5 code examples: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/courses/110/lectures/lists_in_java.htm

Comment: Yep. You see it in old code sometimes: `value = (String)map.get(key);` Some old code (like Eclipse) uses arrays to avoid the casting, which is equally painful (since they can't be resized conveniently).